# Windows phone app development in WP8 SDK

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I am a Windows Phone 7 app developer. Now I am using Visual Studio 2010 and WP7 SDK and Windows 7 OS. But I am planning to install Windows 8 OS and Windows Phone 8 SDK and Visual Studio 2012 in my system. If I do so, can I develop windows phone 7.0 and windows phone 7.1 apps with WP8 SDK and Visual studio 2012 ?

And also I developed some apps in WP7, So if any bug fix needs, Can I do it using WP8 SDK ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can develop 7.1 Apps and 8.0 apps but NOT 7.0 apps with the 8.0 SDK... Although I think devices with system version prior to 7.1 don't have access to the store so you don't need to maintain a 7.0 version of your app....

Of course any wp7.1 project can be opened with the new SDK 8.0 without problems.

Comment: I have an App that I developed in WP7.0 and it also available in the App Hub. By this "Although I think devices with system version prior to 7.1 don't have access to the store so you don't need to maintain a 7.0 version of your app...." you mean, do I need to change the 7.0 app to 7.1 ?. Because am adding some new features in this app (7.0) and going to upload it in the App Hub next week.

Comment: If you want to use the 8.0SDK you need to update your app to 7.1 as it not support 7.0 projects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Windows 8 and visual studio 2012 support WP7 development. There's a WP7 emulator and you can also connect and use your own WP7 test device.